# Does unique constraint column needs to be added while doing upsert in laravel?

Tags: laravel, postgresql, upsert

For example i have table orders in posgres DB

| id | order_no | account_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 222 | 111 |
| 2 | 444 | 222 |

I have added unique constraint on order_no and account_id column. Now when I added new column and I want data to be unique on this column as well which mean the uniques values should be on (order_no,account_id,ack_id) but I do not want to add [ack_id] in unique clause at database level.

| id | order_no | account_id | ack_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 222 | 111 | 1 |
| 2 | 444 | 222 | 2 |

Now when i am doing **upsert in laravel** it throws below errors:

> Invalid column reference: 7 ERROR:  there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification

DO i need to add ack_id in unique constraint at database level?

Below is my code which i have done for upsert:
`

```
DB::table('order_masters')
  ->upsert($chunk, ['order_no', 'account_id','ack_id'],
     ['colums_to_update']
  );
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error once. The error was on database level, not laravel.

The solution was by removing previous unique constraint and add new unique combo.

In your case from (order_no, account_id) to (order_no, account_id, ack_id).

Try this and hope it helps.

Comment: I don't want to add this on the database level. Is it possible to manage on the code level

Comment: If only on the code level, I'm not so sure if upsert() is the way to go. Than again I might be wrong.